Diophantine eqation: $x^2 + y^2 = 12 .z^2$
Find number of Integer: $x^2+y^2=12z^2$(1)
Let $x=6u$ and $y=6v$
(1)$\Rightarrow 36u^2+36v^2=12z^2$
$\Leftrightarrow 3(u^2+v^2)=z^2$
So, $z^2 \vdots 3 \Rightarrow z \vdots3 \Rightarrow GCD(x,y,z)=3 $
Equation (1): No solution.
Everyone help me, check and give me some ways solution?

Please edit to include your efforts.  Also, note that the question in the header isn't the same as the one in the body.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, we can show that both $x$ and $y$ must have the same parity. This means they must both be even because if they are both odd then $x^2$ and $y^2$ each leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $4$, so the LHS has only $1$ factor of $2$, but the RHS has at least $2$ factors of $2$. Thus, $x=2x_1$ and $y=2y_1$, giving $x_1^2+y_1^2=3z^2$, which is answered in the duplicate question. Note I found it using an Approach0 search.

If you simply let $r=2z$, the equation is recast as $x^2+y^2=3r^2$, and you get directly to the same kind of equation as in John Omielan's comment.
